# DocBlocks and Coda

Tags: php, coda, docblocks

I was just wondering if anybody was aware of any plug-ins that would make Coda use my php docBlocks..?

I have searched the programs itself and there doesn't seem to be the options for it.

I have also done a fairly thorough google search and came up trumps.